# Eslint with ts-standard save issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, standards, typescript-eslint

Its my first time using both Typescript and Eslint, I have an issue with the save fix, when I save my project it doesnt change the file with the settings I provide:

This is my eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  overrides: [],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
  },
  plugins: ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  rules: {
    indent: ["error", 2],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    quotes: [2, "single", { avoidEscape: true }],
    semi: ["error", "never"],
  },
};
```

And this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
    "lint": "ts-standard",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node build/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "18.13.0",
    "@types/validator": "13.7.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.52.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.52.0",
    "eslint": "8.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "2.0.0",
    "ts-standard": "12.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.20.1",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.6",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "16.0.3",
    "express": "4.18.2",
    "morgan": "1.10.0",
    "pg": "8.9.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "sequelize": "6.28.0",
    "sequelize-typescript": "2.1.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parserOptions": {
      "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "extends": [
      "./node-modules/ts-standard/eslintrc.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

To fix it I tried with commands on the console like:

```
./node-module/ts-standard/eslintrc.json --fix
```

Also this adding this to the package.json:

```
"@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
    "error",
    "single",
    {
      "allowTemplateLiterals": true
    }
  ]
```

I also fix this by simply changing the settings from *simple* to *double* but I want simple quotes for my config